# What mechanism does Doctrine ORM use to create 'persistant' objects?

Tags: php, orm, doctrine, doctrine-orm

I've recently begun exploring ORM tools such as Doctrine, and in my reading I'm learning that Doctrine creates 'persistant classes' -- which I might be understanding this incorrectly as objects that persist across multiple http requests. So I'm curious how Doctrine accomplishes this, do they store serialized classes on the filesystem, in a database, as data in a cookie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They store it in a database, using [doctrine dbal](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/dbal). The choice of the database is up to you, and very many differents RDBMS are supported. [This overview of the doctrine projects](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects) shows that there are also ODM projects (in beta or alpha release though) if you choose to use a NoSQL system like MongoDB, CouchDB, etc...

Comment: Interesting, are the tables that doctrine uses auto-generated?

Comment: @CaseyFlynn you essentially tell Doctrine how to "map" your objects into database tables - this can be done in differnet ways, check the manual - and doctrine then can generate and execute SQL to create the tables based on your mappings.